# Handling final page in Python paginated API request

Tags: python, request

I'm requesting Microsoft's Graph API, where I'm using the following function to request multiple pages. I'm trying to request all pages, merge the json files and finally write them to a `pandas` dataframe.

```
v = "v1.0"
r = "/users?$filter=userType eq 'Member'&$select=displayName,givenName,jobTitle,mail,department&$top=200"

def query(v, r):
    all_records = []
    url = uri.format(v=v, r=r)
    
    while True:
        if not url:
            break
        result = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
        if result.status_code == 200:
            json_data = json.loads(result.text)
            all_records = all_records + json_data["value"]
            url = json_data["@odata.nextLink"]
    return all_records
```

The `while-loop` goes through all the pages, but when I run the function I'm getting a error:

```
KeyError: '@odata.nextLink'
```

I assume this is because the loop reaches the final page, and thus the `'@odata.nextLink'` cannot be found. But how can I handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing

```
url = json_data["@odata.nextLink"]
```

which suggest `json_data` is `dict`, so you should be able to use `.get` method which returns default value when key not found (`None` by default), please try doing following and write if it does work as excepted:

```
url = json_data.get("@odata.nextLink")
if url is None:
    print("nextLink not found")
else:
    print("nextLink found")
```